# Propensity Score Matching on Pre-treatment Covariates

Tags: r, regression, propensity-scores, matching

I plan to do a propensity score matching and then do a Difference-in-Difference design. I'd like to only match using pre-treatment covariates. However, when I use the MatchIt package in R, I could not specify the time periods to be before treatment. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You can name variables in matchit.  So, rename your variables so that they reflect time period. You will probably also have to restructure your data from "long" to "wide".

Comment: Is this a question primarily about programming (i.e., using MatchIt)?

Comment: Propensity score matching, especially when compared to covariate adjustment, is very inefficient.  Why that choice?